# Read properties file from jsp page without using MVC frameworks

Tags: javascript, servlets

My properties file is at location. `/WebContant/WEB-INF/myproperties.properties`

```
label1.textbox.name=VEHICAL_NO
label2.textbox.name=OTS_NO
label3.textbox.name=Km
```

I have to use this file in my (jsp) file

Comment: what do you want to read, i mean what properties, posting your code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

the above posted properties I have to read in my jsp file instead of using labels for the text boxes

```
<tr>
<td>I have to use my properties file here 

<input type="text" name="vehno" size="20"></td>

<td>**KM**<input type="text" name="km" size="20"></td></tr>
```